# Use EF to delete a record by id, if id does not exist, an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The code looks like this:

```
try
{
    Student stu = new Student() { ID = id };
    db.Entry(stu).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    int result = db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DataException e)
{

}
```

The exception is:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

...but I don't want to get an exception, I want get the number of affected rows, like `0`.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Why don't you check if that object is exist first?

Comment: +1 I agree that this would be useful. In many cases we don't care if the object that we want to remove from a collection still exists. We just want to make sure that it does not exist anymore. Compare for instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx (`List<T>.Remove`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try{
var student= db.Students.First(x => x.ID== 1);
db.Students.DeleteObject(student);
db.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{return 0;}
```

Comment: I'd rather use .FirstOrDefault() and then check if the result is null. Otherwise you will get an exception in your catch block, but could you be sure where the exception comes from? It could be from the querying, deleting, etc....

Comment: Yes,use that,I am not sure where the exception comes from.
But,I only query it before I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

It throws an error because you are attaching an object that may not exist in the database at all.

So you need to first check if it exist and if yes, then delete it, otherwise, ignore it or return an error code that the object doesn't exist.

Another approach would be to just load the object and call the `Remove`

```
try
{
    if(db.Students.Any(s=>s.ID == id)
    {
      Student stu = new Student() { ID = id };
      db.Entry(stu).State = EntityState.Deleted;
      int result = db.SaveChanges();
    }

    
}
catch (DataException e)
{

}
```

The second approach:

```
        var student= db.Students.Find(id);
        if(student != null) {
          db.Students.Remove(student);
          db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Really not sure what you mean in your second approach. what's db.Students.student? and what's item? Did you mean db.Students.Remove(student)? In that case, student could be null and Remove(student) will throw an exception.

Comment: @demonicdaron, sorry for the typo. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind fetching the entities from database just to delete them, you could do

```
db.Students.RemoveRange(db.Students.Where(x => x.Id == ID));
```

If you are more concerned about fetching the entry data, use one of the check if exists, delete by ID ways.

If you are concerned about reducing the amount of database roundtrips, use a custom SQL command similar to the following (maybe convert to stored procedure).

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from \"Schema\".\"Students\" where ID = @p0", id);
```

However, I think you shouldn't use EF at all, if the last example is your option. You lose abstraction and suddenly need to care for schema and table names in SQL etc.

Comment: I think that db.Students.Where(x => x.Id == ID) will fetch the entity anyway

Comment: @teroplut sure... *"If you don't mind fetching the entities from database ..."*. Maybe the 2nd paragraph of my answer is not clear enough, but I would need to re-think the whole thing in order to write it better. Are you trying to solve any specific problem?

Comment: Your second paragraph is definitely not clear enough :) Please provide an example of "one of the check if exists, delete by ID ways".

Comment: Does the first example only do 1 call to the DB (since you are not using .ToList() after the where)?

Comment: @demonicdaron oh dear... its like reading code from 5 years ago, just with regular text. I don't even know where I should start here. I probably meant to reference the answer from HaithamShaddad, when I talked about "delete by ID ways". The first example does a lot of round tripping, not just one call.

Comment: The first example also doesn't completely solve the problem. If the record gets deleted before `SaveChanges()` you'd still get the same exception.