# DbUpdateConcurrencyException on Remove when trying to delete an entry from DbSet without loading it first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I'm trying to delete an entry without loading it from the DB first. I've tried tons of various approaches (all I managed to find in Internet), but none of them seem to work:

`Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.`

For example, this code fails:

```cs
using (var dbContext = _dbContextCreator())
{
     var report = new DataAccess.AssetReport { Id = id };
     dbContext.AssetReports.Attach(report);
     dbContext.AssetReports.Remove(report);
     await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

`AssetReport` looks like that.

```cs
public class AssetReport
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public AssetReportType Type { get; set; }
    public AssetReportStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

This entry exists in the DB. Other requests do not fail. Executing `dbContext.AssetReports.Any` in the same context returns `true`. Removing a record just loaded from the DB also works.

Comment: Sanity check: does an `AssetReport` record exist in the DB for the given `id`? If not, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467554/use-ef-to-delete-a-record-by-id-if-id-does-not-exist-an-exception-is-thrown?rq=1)

Comment: @devNull It does. Other requests do not fail. `Any` returns `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463568/entity-framework-delete-without-select-and-optimistic-concurrency

Comment: @IsmarMujagic The answer supposes to use a 3rd party library, but I'd like to shed some light onto the roots of the issue and avoid using extensions.

Comment: Can you please add the entities for AssetReportType and AssetReportStatus? Also, is this EF6 or EFCore? The example you have certainly *does* work for deleting an entity on a new context without loading it, though I suspect references are tripping it up. (Normally though this would result in FK violations)